# Using KLone for web development

Tags: c, web-frameworks

Would anyone be kind enough to share about your experience using [KLone](http://www.koanlogic.com/index.html) in a web project? Mostly, in what context are you using it?

Their home page mentions that:

> KLone is a fully-featured, multiplatform, web application development framework, targeted especially for embedded systems and appliances.

However, to what extent if any is it useful for general purpose web dev?
Thanks

Comment: If you wonder what it has to do with C, visit KLone's page, try putting 2 and 2 together, might help, get new glasses if you can't see c